# how run applications in android phone instead emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium

My emulator wastes my time because it is slow. So I want to run my applications to test on my samsung phone. However, I cannot make a connection between Titanium Studio and my device. I checked several solutions but I could not . 
Is there any solution you could suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the correct driver for your device in your desktop. As you are using samsung there is a software called kies. you have to install it.

Then 
**Enable the USB debugging mode in your device.**

Finally change the **Run configuration** in eclipse.

It will do work.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install the ADB drivers for your android device. See this video to find out how to install adb drivers for any android device.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDA8PpPSFuk

There is a link in the comments in that video that contains the driver files. Download it. Connect your phone to your PC and enable USB Debugging Mode. Then, follow the instructions shown in the video.

After installing the drivers, your device will show up in the Devices list in Eclipse. Select it and the application should run fine on your device

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why the downloaded driver is not being viewed by pc. My OS warns me that the downloaded file was could not be opened due to harmful. Besides, I enabled to USB debugging so I am trying to download ADB drivers.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Also, just recheck if you are able to open the file. I had installed the driver today afternoon and everything went well.

Comment: I use win7 pro. I have checked again and again, nothing changed.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q5ppfijfquz3qpc/6cpEmDMGfS

Download the drivers from this link.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the USB debugging mode in your device, then connect your device, it should work.

Comment: Also turn the install apps from unknown sources function on.

Answer (score 0):

Install Samsung Kies that will detect your devices. Change the device setting debug mode on and run your app with active device